# Python Canopy kernel keeps crashing

Tags: python, canopy

When I restart my kernel in Canopy (latest version), it goes into a loop where the kernel will crash repeatedly, and even when restarting repeatedly, it does not exit this loop. It's very annoying to have to do this when something doesn't work, and I'm trying to avoid having to re-install. Any suggestions? P.S.: I have contacted Enthought.

Comment: Any logs? Could you clarify exactly which version for future reference?

Comment: I have no logs for this, as it doesn't have any error that displays in the error log. In fact, there is no error at all, it seems. I cannot determine the exact version of Python, but my Python updates with the Canopy updates, so I'm guessing Python 3.4.2. I have Canopy version 1.4.1.255.

Comment: Canopy 1.4.1 is *not* the latest version of Canopy. See https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website

Comment: Also responded on your support ticket.

Comment: Have updated. Problem continues. Error code 1.

Comment: Responding on ticket.

Comment: Have done all steps @JonathanMarch . Still doesn't work.

Comment: Please respond on ticket.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did.

Install Canopy 1.5.5

Now open Canopy terminal

Go to Package Manager-> Updates -> Install all 7 updates
Once you install all the updates , you will see both the kernel and 'pip' getting updated.

I have not encountered the 'Python kernel has crashed error since then'.

Note: I have a Linux OS

Comment: Updating also worked on Windows 10 on 20.07.2018 for a similar problem.